# using the where clause + new constraint with args?

Tags: c#, .net, where-clause

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
    public static T CreateSomething<T>(SomeType a) where T : SomeMicrosoftBaseClass, new()
    {
        var newElement = new T { SomeProperty = a};
        DoStuff();
        return newElement;
    }
```

and now I need to change the code so I could pass to the constructor of SomeMicrosoftBaseClass a boolean argument - which I can only set on construction.

since the "new()" constraint requires a public parameter-less constructor, and since I couldn't use an interface or modify SomeMicrosoftBaseClass, I'm using reflection like so:

```
var newElement = (T) (typeof (T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(SomeType) }).Invoke(new object[] { a }));
```

can anybody suggest a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx):

```
var newElement = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T),a);
```

Comment: just be aware Activate.CreateInstance is incredibly slow in comparison to new()